# Request en NodeJS sincronizado

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Actualmente, si ejecuto este código en la consola, primero obtengo el segundo console.log y después el primero. ¿Cómo puedo hacer para que espere a terminar de ejecutar el request?

```
var request = require("request");
var aqi;
var url = "https://XXX"
  request({
      url: url,
      json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
          aqi = body.data[0].aqi;
          console.log(aqi);
      }
  })
console.log(aqi);
```

Comment: es solo una pregunta de concepto o es por que no quieres avanzar hasta que se cumpla el primer request?

Comment: No quiero avanzar hasta que se cumpla el primer request

Answer (score 0):

Podrías transformar el request en una promesa como se puede ver en el siguiente código:

```
   const util = require('util')
   const request = require("request");
   const requestPromise = util.promisify(request);
   var url = "https://XXX"
   const response = await requestPromise({
         url: url,
         json: true
   });
   console.log('response', response.body );
```